# location.getLocation() when GPS is enabled but can't reach satellite

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a working app that sorts places by distance from my location or alphabetically if the user does not want to enable GPS. Everything works well, but I would like to enhance my app by automatically sorting alphabetically if a satellite can not be reached, say from a basement, or if it is just taking over a given period of time, say 5 seconds. Is this even possible? I haven't been able to find anything like this. I'd like to just pop up a message that says "Can't reach satellite, sorting alphabetically" instead of the user having to do anything themselves.

Thanks for your responses and your time.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override your `LocationListener`'s `onStatusChanged()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
      if (status == LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE || status == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE){
        // GPS unavailable: send notification
      } else {
         // you're out of a basement, continue using GPS 
      }     
  }
}
```

Android documentation promises that if a provider is unavailable at the moment you subscribe your `LocationListener`, it invokes this callback immediately.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find and the else was funny enough that I had to explain it to my wife... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some combination of `Out of Service` and `Temporarily Unavailable` in the `Location Listener`'s `onStatusChanged()`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html